# Bootstrap 4, CSS - Hide Text on a tab menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a CSS issue hiding the text in my side menu and leave the font awesome icons on mobile view, and I can't think of any reasonable solution. I use bootstrap 4

Then code of my sidebar menu

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <a class="active" href="#Link0"><i class="fas fa-walking"></i> Link0</a>
  <a href="#link1"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Link1</a>
  <a href="#link2"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Link2</a>
  <a href="#link3"><i class="fas fa-headset"></i> Link3</a>
</div>
```

According to the bootstrap manual, I should be able to hide any element between any suitable tag with `class="d-SM-none d-MD-block"`. My problem is that I want the icon on the left-hand side to stay visible for mobile view and hide the text but when I put the text between `<div>` tags text always appears one line down from the icon. I tried `<i> <p>` tags and still the same issue and btw the text doesn't hide anyways :D
Any help welcome!

What I tried and didn't work:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="sidebar">
  <a class="active" href="#Link0"><i class="fas fa-walking"></i> <div class="d-sm-none d-md-block">Link0</div></a><!--Text is one line down from icon-->
  <a href="#link1"><i class="fas fa-users"></i><p class="d-sm-none d-md-block"> Link1</p></a><!--Text is one line down from icon-->
  <a href="#link2"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Link2</a>
  <a href="#link3"><i class="fas fa-headset"></i> Link3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry it's a bit confusing as my English is not great... the main idea is to keep icon and text next to each other like other links 2 and 3 this is the main problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hidding part works fine, the problem is that you try to add some elements that are default display with block (`div`, `p`) so replace that by `span`.

Then don't use class `d-md-block` as you are in `a` that has a default `display: inline`. So you should use class `d-md-inline`.

### Result:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="sidebar">
  <a class="active" href="#Link0"><i class="fas fa-walking"></i> <span class="d-sm-none d-md-inline">Link0</span></a><!--Text is one line down from icon-->
  <a href="#link1"><i class="fas fa-users"></i><span class="d-sm-none d-md-inline"> Link1</span></a><!--Text is one line down from icon-->
  <a href="#link2"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Link2</a>
  <a href="#link3"><i class="fas fa-headset"></i> Link3</a>
</div>
```